# Two environments in the same application

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to build Environment for different profile (with relayted property sources)?

For example: while app running with prod profile i want to have configuration beans for dev profile.

I am using spring boot 2 (with new Binder API)

Any help is appreciated.

P.S.: I wand same configuration objects but with profile specific values.

Example: 
application.yml

```
spring:
   profiles: dev
server:
   address: 127.0.0.1
---
spring:
   profiles: prod
server:
   address: 192.168.1.120
```

Config bean:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("server")
@Validated
public static class ServerConf {
   private final InetAddress address;
...
}
```

main goal is to have ServerConf as a bean related to active profile and set of objects of ServerConf class related to specific profile or set of beans like ServerConfProd, ServerConfDev

Ideally i am looking for something similar to this:

```java
StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
env.setActiveProfiles("prod");
MutablePropertySources propertySources = env.getPropertySources();

propertySources.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:application-prod.properties"));
propertySources.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:application.properties"));
ServerConf prodServerConf = Binder.get(env).bind("server", Bindable.of(ServerConf.class)).get();
```

It works but has a lot of disadvantages: validation would not work, property sources manually set ...

Comment: you may configure spring boot on two different ports with same values

Comment: If i understand are you looking at `@Profile("dev")` annotation

Comment: Thanks but no, the case is little bit more complicated

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set multiple active profiles as follow:

```
spring.prifiles.active:
- prod
- dev
```

With this approach al beans defined with `@Profiles("prod")` and `@Profiles("dev")` will be initialized. Be aware that there shouldn't be any amboguous bean definition.

---

If you prefer to just set `prod` as active profile, you can still tell Spring to include other profiles:

```
spring.profiles.include:
  - dev
  - other
```

For more reference take a look at [profiles chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

## UPDATE

Your idea won't work: one property will override the other.

I would handle `serverConf.address` as a Map:

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
server:
  addresses:
    dev: 127.0.0.1
---
spring:
  profiles: prod
server:
  addresses:
    prod: 192.168.1.120
```

**ServerConf.java**

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("server")
@Validated
public class ServerConf {
   private final Map<String, InetAddress> addresses = new HashMap<>();
   //...
}
```

In this way, if you activate both profiles you'll get a map with 2 keys (`dev` and `prod`). I personally find it a bit ugly, but should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks but it would not work in my case. I wand profile specific values for the same properties.

Comment: May you edit your question and provide some examples?

Comment: have wrote an example. Hope it will help clarify what i want. @noiaverbale

Comment: Thank you for your time but this is not what I want

Comment: You might want to explain your usecase in more detail I see no reason why the answer wouldn't work,

Comment: @LifeIsGoodMF if you really really want ServerConfProd and ServerConfDev beans you need to prefix their properties with a specific attribute (e.g. `dev.server` and `prod.server`) and create 2 different classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties("<env>.server")`. But then you have to check those beans existance and loose the majority of Spring environment properties features IMHO.

Comment: @Daren Forsythe It would not work because there is no way to change original ServerConf bean